# Webpack ignoring an array variable when bundling

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using webpack to bundle multiple js files. One of the js files holds a single array variable that seems to be getting ignored in the bundling and I can't figure out why. I've put in 2 test alerts just to see if any of the js is compiling, and I can see these are successfully been bundled. The variable in between seems to be ignored and I'm not sure why.

This is my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
        //common: ['./src/js/common.js'],
        quoteBuilder: [
            './src/js/map-style.js',
            './src/js/quote-builder.js'
        ],
        contact: ['./src/js/contact.js']
    },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: '[name].min.js'
  },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015'
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

and this is my map-style.js file:

```
alert('test1');
var mapStyle = [
    {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "weight": "2.00"
            }
        ]
    },

    ...

    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#ffffff"
            }
        ]
    }
];
alert('test2');
```

When I check the bundled js file, this is what's being generated:

```
alert("test1");alert("test2")
```

What have I missed here?

Comment: My guess is that it is left out because the variable is never used. You don't export the variable or do anything with it. The reason the alerts stay is they have side effects. What happens when you add `console.log(mapStyle)`? Does the variable show up in the generated output? If you don't want to use the variable in the current file, make sure you export it. Or if you want to set a global variable use `global.mapStyle = ...`. I suggest sticking with the export since [global variables are bad](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

Comment: Thank you @3limin4t0r - turns out it an export was required too, so I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Webpack is bundling only those variables that are being used somewhere in the program. So, if you do not have your mapStyle variable used anywhere else in the program, it will be ignored. Alert is, I guess, a different thing since it is general, JS function which is why it is bundled. Also, it could be that the way you created inner objects inside mapStyle array causes this issue. You have wrote it like this: "featureType": "all", while it probably should be featureType: "all".

Comment: `{featureType: "all"}` is just a shorthand for `{"featureType": "all"}`. String keys are always valid. Non-string keys are only valid as long as they are valid JavaScript identifiers or numbers. See [Grammar and Types - Object Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals)